# Contact Form 7 Save entries for later

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I am not sure of this is possible or even been done before as cant find much info.

I have a contact form 7 for timesheets that when you submit saves with custom code to a table on the SQL db. This can then be read by the admin.

Now what my client wants is a way for users to fill in the timesheet, save it and then come back and do it again until they are ready to submit.

I know there are other forms out there like WP forms & Gravity that do similar but before I have to go down that route which is extra cost, then rewriting current solution I was wondering of anybody had done this or something similar.

Thanks

I am trying to first get around the validation so nothing takes place, then I can call the save function which will be same as my current save but different table.

Comment: It's like saving "draft" and editing it multiple times, than saving saving it as final?

Comment: Yes save draft and then when they are finished they can submit as the timesheet needs to be signed off.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with the [Post My CF7 Form](https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-my-contact-form-7/) extension which allows you to map a form to an existing post or a custom post.  The extension has a `[save]` submit field which submit the form in draft mode, bypassing the validation.  The user needs to be logged in to save submissions and reload previous draft submission into the form.

Here is a video [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fQP-_o9vLjs&list=PLblJwjs_dFBtQzwPMoMFf-vsXkhuKHKhV&index=5) explaining how to do this.

In Your case, since you're saving your submission to custom table, you can delete the draft post the plugin saves when the form is successfully submitted for a given user.